# I can't use the command ' python manage.py makemigrations' in django VSC

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-model-field

I already did 'python manage.py migrations'. Now i want to create '0001_inital.py' file in migrations with the code 'python manage.py makemigrations'. Firstly this is my models.py;

```
from django.db import models



class Room(models.Model):
    #host =
    #topic =
    name = models.CharField(max_Length=200)
    description = models.Textfield(null=True, blank = True)
    #participants = 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

And here is the some of the errors that when i write 'python manage.py makemigrations'.

> File "", line 1006, in
> _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 883, in
> exec_module
>
> File "", line 241, in
> _call_with_frames_removed
>
> File "C:\Users\c.aktel\OneDrive\Masaüstü\laan\base\models.py", line
> 5, in 
> class Room(models.Model):   File "C:\Users\c.aktel\OneDrive\Masaüstü\laan\base\models.py", line 8, in
> Room name = models.CharField(max_Length=200)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\c.aktel\OneDrive\Masaüstü\laan\new_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init*_.py",
> line 1121, in **init**
> super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: Field.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'max_Length'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `max_length` not `max_Length` and `TextField` not `Textfield` so the correct is:

```py
class Room(models.Model):
    #host =
    #topic =
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank = True)
    #participants = 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Also I'd recommend you to use `f-strings` in `__str__()` method of model.

Then run both the migration commands.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Also i will use that f-strings. Thank you also for it.